# How to make same installation on multiple machines?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

What is the easy way to make the "same" Windows installation of QGIS (same menu, same plugins, same prefs...) on multi-PCs, 10 or 12 laptops?

Comment: Which operating systems?

Comment: Perhaps you could just clone the whole machine image (e.g. with Ghost or Clonezilla)

Answer (score 1):

try create portable QGIS with same plugins, prefs... Some info on site [gis-lab.info](http://gis-lab.info/forum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=9707&start=15)

Comment: on window. HasT, thank, but the russian is not my language and traduction from russian is a little bit difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

How about rolling your own live cd (or dvd or usb stick) with stripped Ubuntu Linux distribution? 
You can add QGIS, all the geospatial goodies and even your own data. That would leave you with pretty much your own custom version of [OSGeo-Live](http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html) that people can enjoy with or without installation on their machines.

[Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) or [other tools](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/10-scripts-to-create-your-own-linux-distribution-665247) can assist you with that process.

Answer (score 1):

there is a portable qgis for windows  here (English!) hope this helps

edit: url
http://www.archaeogeek.com/blog/2012/09/12/portable-gis-v3-released/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ComputingGisAndArchaeologyInTheUk+%28Open+Source+Computing+and+GIS+in+the+UK%29

Comment: Can you try the link again?

Comment: @BradHards: sorry, please try again